# capacitor value substitution

Tags: capacitor

I have an audio circuit im building from schematics. . The schematic calls for 30nF, 220nF, 6.8nF, 22nF, 5nF, and 2.2nF capacitors ...all of which I cannot find to order. . I even converted these values into microfarads and picofarads and can't locate these parts either. . Can I substitute a closer more common value capacitor for each of these?  I can send you the schematic if it helps answer my question

Comment: We can't even begin to speculate without a schematic.

Comment: Apart from 5nf for which you might get away with 4.7 or 5.1nf, these are all standard values. Where are you looking that won't supply them?

Comment: @MattYoung combining caps in series or parallel to make a specific value wouldn't require a schematic...

Comment: @Passerby Sure, but where did the OP say anything about doing that? He wants to substitute for common values.

Comment: Like I said I can email a schematic!!!! Also had forgotten thatythatyou can combime caps in series to get the values needed thank u for reminding me. . Also I have tried small bear, nte, jameco, digikey, newark, and radioshack.   All I canfcanfInd is the 22nf so it the others can't be very common

Comment: These are all common values. Ditch your inept supplier.

Answer (score 1):

You must be looking in the wrong place. Go to digikey.com and enter the appropriate parametric search, and you'll find all the components you want:
http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/capacitors/ceramic-capacitors/131083?k=capacitor

Substituting capacitors used for bypassing can work just fine; typically more is better in those cases (as long as ESR and voltage rating is sufficient.) Substituting capacitors used as part of a tuned filter is much less straightforward. Thus, to answer your question, we need to know the role of each of those capacitors.

Answer (score 0):

If these capacitors form filters etc. then its not a good idea to just change values. The original design specified them for a reason. You could make up the values by series/parallel connections e.g. a 5nF can be made with 2 x 10nF connected in series, a 30nF can be made with three 10nF in parallel.